# jquery to modify a link

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<TD class=ms-sctabcf >
    <A href="http://localdev.industrial.com:80/en-US/SearchM3/Pages/results.aspx?k=test+contenttype%3a%22IABusinessProduct%22&amp;s=IA_xx-XX_Content">All Results
</A></TD>
```

I need a jquery function that removes the "contenttype%3a%22IABusinessProduct%22" from the anchor tag.

Something like this should do it:

```
function removeContentTypeFromAllResultsLinkOnGeneralSearch(){
    var anchorTag =  $('.ms-sctabcf').has('text=All Results').find('a');
    var currentLink = anchorTag.link;
    // remove the "contenttype%3a%22IABusinessProduct%22" from the link. ( match any content type value using regular expression)

    var modifiedLink = currentLink.regex.replace("contenttype%3a%22.*?%22",""); 
    anchorTag.link = modifiedLink;
}
```

Can you help me turn my pseudocode into a real jquery/javascript function?

Also, I need to select the a tag only if it has the inner text of "All Results". what is the jquery selector for that?

Comment: I think your second code block is missing a quote. You found it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href").replace(/contenttype%3a%22IABusinessProduct%22/, ""));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").each(function(){
  var str = $(this).attr('href');
  var myhref = str.split('+contenttype');
  $(this).attr('href', myhref[0]);
});
```

Might be a better way, but this way works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
    function removeAllContentTypesFromLinks() {
        var $a = $('a');
        $a.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                href = $(this).attr('href').split('+contenttype')[0];
            $this.attr('href', href);
        });
    }
    removeAllContentTypesFromLinks();
}(jQuery));
```

That should do the trick. A jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/LPwvp/4/